# How to block developers tools (like Firebug) in a page?

Tags: javascript, browser, firebug

I need to block tools like Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools in a specific page. How can I do that?

I found this code and it works for Firebug:

```
<script>
   if( window.console && window.console.firebug ){
      alert("Sorry! This system does not support Firebug.\nClick OK to log out.");
      window.location='/login_out';
   }
</script>
```

But not for Chrome Developer Tools and others. Does anyone know a way of blocking it to most of developer tools?

Just FYI, I need this to avoid users to change the html code. I'm using hidden inputs in a form, and sadly, I really need to do this instead using cURL or something similar. Sorry if "developer tools" was not clear enough.

Comment: I will just enter into the html source code and remove this lines:P

Comment: You can't reliably...those tools belong to the user and a web page has no right to deny access to them. Anyone who knows what they're doing will be able to remove your restrictions easily.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @Gilden, I need to avoid persons to change some hidden inputs.

Comment: @ItaloAndré you must validate your input server-side anyway. Nothing stops me from downloading you page and modifying the hidden inputs by hand. Instead, I think you would get way better answers had you asked about input validation or something similar.

Comment: @Gilden Thanks for the help and advises. I know that using hidden inputs is not a good way of coding. But this was a limitation in the system I'm suing here at work.

Comment: @ItaloAndré using Hidden inputs is not bad, bad is not validate the data provided by that inputs in the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother. You can't disable it, and frankly - there's never a good reason to do it. Don't send your users anything you don't want them to see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will follow your advise and I know that what I was asking for is not 'nice' for the web. But it was because a limitation of the system that I'm working, have to live with this. =(

Comment: 'Nice' has nothing to do with it, it's just impossible to prevent browsers or browser tools from accessing the data your website sends them.

Comment: I know that are better ways of doing what I need to do, but I'm being forced to do in a way that is not one of the best. That's what I meant to say.