# How to disable "Inspect Element" plugin programmatically in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, firebug

I have created a website in asp.net, I want to disable "inspect element" property of browser, else anyone can change post, styles on that page and submit.

So please let me know how can I disable it, I tried

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.console || window.console.firebug) {
                console.clear();
            };
        });
```

but not working ?

Comment: Exactly duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151160/how-to-block-developers-tools-like-firebug-in-a-page

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably do anything to prevent the client from modifying the HTML document your application sent or from sending forged requests to your application. It is your responsibility to validate everything the client sends back to you on the server side. The Golden Rule is: "mistrust everything the client sends to you".

Especially any approach based on JavaScript is useless as the user can simply deactivate JavaScript in his browser. Any attempt to temper with the browser's behavior usually only annoys your users and makes them leave.