# Is Dipslay of service calls in browser developer tools like Firebug a security threat?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, firebug

***Note** - It is not a duplicate of that question. The concerns are different. I don't want to disable that firebug let it be open let the user to use all functionality provided by firebug, I only want firebug not to show service calls.*

I may be wrong but I want to ask when browser developer tools like firebug displays service calls and their request response Is it not a security threat? If not why so?

IF it is, Is there any way by which we can hide the display of service calls after build deployment in firebug or developer tools?

[image]

You can see a get request shown by firebug in Mozilla firefox.

I have searched for this but not getting anything fruitful and I am also not able to find any post related to this concern on stackoverflow. If any one has any information please share it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to block developers tools (like Firebug) in a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151160/how-to-block-developers-tools-like-firebug-in-a-page)

Comment: @DaggNabbit It is not a duplicate of that question. The concerns are different. I don't want to disable that firebug, I only want firebug not to show service calls.

Comment: Ok, so you want to partially disable firebug, and the accepted answer on that question is essentially identical to the best answer on this question: *Don't bother. You can't disable it, and frankly - there's never a good reason to do it. Don't send your users anything you don't want them to see.*

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a security issue on any properly designed web site / service. The browser, and requests performed by the browser, should all be considered to be under the user's control. (Indeed, from a security perspective, the browser should be considered an extension of the user, rather than something separate from them.) As such, the user viewing something that's under the user's control is not a risk at all.

If your web site is sending data that the user shouldn't be allowed to see in HTTP(S) requests, **you've done something wrong**. That data should never leave the server at all if it's that sensitive - move the logic that needs it off of the client (e.g, Javascript) and back onto the server side.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But if the architecture depends on rest class only Then how can I hide the data which should not be seen by the user.

Comment: If data should not be seen by the user, then you shouldn't be sending it to them.

Comment: But If I want to exchange some private which should not be displayed to the user, then how the communication is going to take place.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, you could use your server to communicate securely with the service, and then send non-sensitive data back to the client (as mentioned in the last sentence of this answer).

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Store the private data in sessions. Use Cookies / Session Key to identify the user

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I would like to add the following: You don't know what browser the user is using. Even if it says it is Chrome, it could be Firefox or a browser that you never heard of that could circumvent every known protection that other browsers could provide. Assume that the user can read every single bit that you send down the wire, and assume that the user can tamper with every single bit you receive. You can get 1 byte when you expected 50, or 2000000 when you expected 1 or malformed utf8-sequences. Make sure that your application can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

If your web application follows [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) then it would be harmful.

But as long as you make your web application secure with common vulnerabilities like CSRF, XSS taken care of then anyone seeing the request made / response received doesn't matter.